# C++ template choose code block according to type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Is it possible within a C++ template function to enable/disable a block of code *at compile time*, based on the type of a parameter?

(If it is possible, I suspect `std::enable_if` may be part of the solution, but I haven't yet seen how to select a code block at compile time based on that.)

I'm looking to do something like this.

```
template<typename T>
void captureData(T *data, size_t len, T scaleFactor)
{
    initCaptureDevice();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        IF(T is integral type) // determine at compile time which to use
        {
            data[i] = getRawSample();
        }
        ELSE
        {
            data[i] = getRawSample() * scaleFactor;
        }
    }

    cleanup();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what are `IF` and `ELSE` supposed to be?

Comment: @NeilButterworth, some as-yet unknown construct to select the code at compile time.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for C++17's `if constexpr`?

Comment: Couldn't you just overload the function, so you have one version with a scale factor and one without the scale factor? It seems misleading to always have a scale factor parameter but only to apply it in some situations.

Comment: @Cornstalks, I considered that an implementation detail, where I would wrap the template and expose the integer version without the scaleFactor.

Comment: @NeilButterworth. author is looking for something as `static_if` construct of D : https://dlang.org/spec/version.html#staticif

Comment: if constexpr works.. if works with limitations.. enable_if might allow different design..

Comment: What's with the downvotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
template<typename T>
void captureData(T *data, size_t len, T scaleFactor, int anotherParam)
{
    initCaptureDevice();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(std::is_integral<T>::value) // determine at compile time which to use
        {
            data[i] = getRawSample();
        }
        else
        {
            data[i] = getRawSample() * scaleFactor;
        }
    }
    cleanup();
}
```

will work just fine - compiler will remove code of not used branch of `if(constexpr) ... else ...;`

Comment: Or `if (std::is_integral_v<T>)` in C++17 and later

Comment: @c-smile, will the choice be made at compile-time in C++11, or only C++17? And is there a way to eliminate the scaleFactor param for the integer version?

Comment: @cp.engr  at compile time in any C/C++ compiler - that's basic optimization (dead code elimination).

Comment: @cp.engr you can use a default parameter for `scaleFactor` if you move it to be the last parameter.

Comment: @cp.engr ever consider that you're asking too much?

Comment: @MarkRansom, asking too much of the language, or of SO? Regardless, I cleaned up the question and deleted some of my comments. Thanks.